# JavaFX dynamic TableView is not showing all the data from db

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview, front-controller

Why in the table i can only see the values of the first column and not those of others?

This is the statement of the TableView and its TableColumn

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Contratto, String> dataNascita;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Contratto, String> idPrenotazione;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Contratto, String> codAgenzia;

@FXML
private TableView<Contratto> tabellaRicerca;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Contratto, String> codCliente;
```

This is the code that initializes the table values with the values of the database. 
"VisualizzaContratti" is the query that takes all contracts inserted into the database.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resource) {

    tabellaRicerca.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    List<Contratto> listaContratti = (List<Contratto>) fc.processRequest("VisualizzaContratti", null);
    contrattiTable = FXCollections.observableList(listaContratti);
    idPrenotazione.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contratto, String>("numContratto"));
    codCliente.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contratto, String>("codiceCliente"));
    codAgenzia.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contratto, String>("codiceAgenzia"));
    dataNascita.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contratto,String>("inizioNoleggio"));

    tabellaRicerca.setItems(contrattiTable);        

}
```

this code shows only the values of idPrenotazione and not the others.

This is the Contratto model

```
public class Contratto {

public String numContratto;
public String codiceCliente;
public String codiceAgenzia;
public String inizioNoleggio;
public String limiteNoleggio;
public int oraInizio;
public int oraRestituzione;
public String cittàRitiro;
public String cittàRestituzione;
public int kmIllimitati;
public int numKm;
public String numPatente;
public String numCartaCredito;
public String nomeAuto;
public int concluso;


/*
 * Metodi get per mostrare i corrispondenti valori
 */

public String getNumContratto(){
    return numContratto;
}

public String getCodCliente(){
    return codiceCliente;
}

public String getCodAgenzia(){
    return this.codiceAgenzia;
}

public String getDataRitiro(){
    return this.inizioNoleggio;
}

public String getDataRestit(){
    return this.limiteNoleggio;
}

public String getCittàRitiro(){
    return this.cittàRitiro;
}

public String getCittàRestituzione(){
    return this.cittàRestituzione;
}

public int getKmIllimitati(){
    return this.kmIllimitati;
}

public int getOraInizio(){
    return this.oraInizio;
}

public int getOraFine(){
    return this.oraRestituzione;
}

public int getKm(){
    return this.numKm;
}

public String getNumPatente(){
    return numPatente;
}

public String getNumCarta(){
    return numCartaCredito;
}

public String getNome(){
    return this.nomeAuto;
}

public int getConcluso(){
    return this.concluso;
}



/*
 * Metodi set per settare i valori desiderati
 */

public void setNumContratto(String numero){
    this.numContratto = numero;
}

public void setCodiceCliente(String codice) {
    this.codiceCliente = codice;
}

public void setCodiceAgenzia(String codiceA) {
    this.codiceAgenzia = codiceA;
}

public void setOraInizio(int orainizio) {
    this.oraInizio = orainizio;
}

public void setOraFine(int orafine) {
    this.oraRestituzione = orafine;
}

public void setKm(int km) {
    this.numKm = km;
}

public void setInizio(String inizio) {
    this.inizioNoleggio = inizio;
}

public void setFine(String fine) {
    this.limiteNoleggio = fine;
}

public void setCittàRitiro(String cittàRit) {
    this.cittàRitiro = cittàRit;
}

public void setCittàRestituizione(String cittàRest) {
    this.cittàRestituzione = cittàRest;
}

public void setKmIllimitati(int km) {
    this.kmIllimitati = km;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nomeAuto = nome;
}

/*
public void setInizioNoleggio(String inizio){
    this.inizioNoleggio = inizio;
}


public void setLimiteNoleggio(String limite){
    this.limiteNoleggio = limite;
}*/


public void setPatente(String numPatente){
    this.numPatente = numPatente;
}

public void setCarta(String numCarta){
    this.numCartaCredito = numCarta;
}

public void setConcluso(int flag) {
    this.concluso = flag;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add the Contratto model as well?

Comment: I add the Contratto model at the end of the question.